# Problem saving associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save data from User(parent model) when creating/editing a Shop (child model).

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shop, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user #!!!!!!!!!!!!
end
```

My Shop controller:

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @shop = Shop.new
        #@shop.user = current_user
        @shop.build_user
    end
end

def create
    @shop = Shop.new(params[:shop])

    @shop.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
    if @shop.save
        flash[:notice] = t(:shop_created)
        format.html { redirect_to(@shop) }
        format.xml { render :xml => @shop, :status => :created, :location => @shop }
    else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml { render :xml => @shop.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
 end

end
```

Shop page:

```
<% form_for @shop, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%- f.fields_for :user do |user| %>
        <%= user.text_field :name, :live => true %>
    <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

All examples that I found about saving associated models are when saving from User (parent) N children ( my Shop model). In those cases I understand where define accepts_nested_attributes_for.

My case is inverse.

Q: How can I save User data when submitting on Shop form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, the accepts_nested_attributes_for is meant to be on the parent model, in this case the user. So if you do the reverse, and save on the user model, when passing the shop nested attributes, it should work. I have to admit i haven't tried this, but it's what i got from reading this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Yes, I understand what you say, what you described is the typical usage of "accepts_nested_attributes_for" (and maybe the only). But in my case I don't want to save user data by submitting the user form but the shop form. Maybe I should face a different approach if accepts_nested_attributes_for is not suitable for my case. Maybe the right question here is: which is the best way to save parent data when submitting on child form ?

Comment: I don't know if there's a prettier way of doing that, except to create a method as part of the shop model, that grabs its user parent object, and sets the attribute values individually. Basically using the params hash, manually specify each key to return the value you want for each field of that model.